# Finding hassle in Randomized QuickSort(Where pivot is a random number)

Tags: c, quicksort

```
int partition(int arr[], int low, int up)
{
    int temp,i,j,pivot,k,swap;
    i=low+1;
    j=up;
    k=(rand() % (up + 1 - low)) + low;

    pivot=arr[k];
    swap=arr[low];
    arr[low]=arr[k];
    arr[k]=swap;    
    while(i<=j)
    {
        while((arr[i] < pivot) && (i < up))
        {
            i++;
        }
        while(arr[j] > pivot)
        {
            j++;
        }
        if(i < j)
        {
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }

    }
    arr[low]=arr[j];
    arr[j]=pivot;
    return j;

}
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code but it's not working. When I gave 3 , 2  , 4 as input a windows dialogue box popped up "RandQck.exe has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly".  Now I have made a little bit modification in the section i.e.

```
swap=arr[low];
arr[low]=arr[k];
arr[k]=swap;
pivot=arr[low];
```

and giving input 3 , 2, 4 the output is 3,3,3. I know the question is naïve but please help to figure out the problem and if possible rectify it. The rest portion i.e the main , the Quick function is correct. Problem is only with the Partition function.

Comment: "*I don't know what's wrong with my code but it's not working.*" <- did you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: You have a *crash*. To find out where you should run in a debugger. And to get our help you need to show us a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My bad ..I shouldn't ask this question like this way..But I didn't have any other choice..I'm totally thought experts  could help me..I helpless with this problem..what should I do then?

Comment: @AndrewWatson as the comment above yours states: the easiest way to find the exact spot where a program crashes is to run it in a debugger.

Comment: btw, if you don't know **anything** about your input, just always picking the first element is *just as good* as a random one.

Comment: @FelixPalmen that's not correct. *You* might not know, but the party from whom the data comes *does* know it. That's one good reason why randomized qsort exists.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala no idea what you're trying to say. Without assumptions on the data, any method of picking a pivot is just as good

Comment: @FelixPalmen that's not what you said. You said if the programmer does not know anything about the data then picking the first pivot is as good, which is wrong, qsort is notoriously slow with worst-case input. If you randomize, then you're guaranteed to get worst case inputs only in a fraction of cases, even if a) feeding in worst case input by accident twice, b) being attacked by a malicious party.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that's of course correct, but I'd consider this already an *assumption* (the possibility to receive pre-sorted data exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  while(arr[j] > pivot)
        {
            j++;
        }
```

Here is the problem. j++ making your array out of index. Make it j--. i.e

```
while(arr[j] > pivot)
        {
            j--;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This, in all probability, causes your program to crash:

```
while(arr[j] > pivot){
    j++;
}
```

The variable `j` is initialized with up and keeps on being incremented and goes out of bounds of the array.

Here is a partition function (C++) that I use which you can implement using a randomized initial pivot:

```
int partition(int* arr, int l, int u){
    int flag=0;
     int p = l; //I have initialized pivot with l, but it you can  choose a random value as well.
    while(l<u){
        if(flag == 0){
            while(arr[u]>arr[p]) u--;
            swap(&arr[u], &arr[p]);
            flag=1;
            p=u;
        }
        else if(flag == 1){
            while(arr[l]<arr[p]) l++;
            swap(&arr[l], &arr[p]);
            flag=0;
            p=l;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)